# MySQL OR AND Syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax

Just starting to learn MySQL so a noob question and my first on StackOverflow.

Lets say I have 12 order statuses and I want to select total's from 5 of them. I would use:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM `orders` WHERE 
order_status_id = '1' OR 
order_status_id = '2' OR
order_status_id = '5' OR
order_status_id = '9' OR
order_status_id = '12';
```

Is there a shorter way to get this? Something like...

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM `bd_order` WHERE
 order_status_id = ('1' OR '2' OR '5' OR '9' OR '12');
```

Comment: I do not understand the conditions because they are redundant. Any value greater than 5 will definitely be greater than 2. Am I missing something here?

Comment: My apologies, they should be equal to... edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `IN`

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS total 
FROM `bd_order` 
WHERE order_status_id in (1,2,5,9,12);
```

Comment: Please remember that the parser will still make ORs out of it (at least in PostgreSQL). It's just easier for you to write, but to optimize the time it will do exactly what you wrote in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the statements in brackets:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM `orders` WHERE (
order_status_id = '1' OR 
order_status_id > '2' OR
order_status_id > '5' OR
order_status_id > '9' OR
order_status_id > '12'
);
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM `orders` WHERE order_status_id IN (1,2,5,9,12);
```